# Lambda Python Docker - [ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'main'

Tags: python, docker, aws-lambda

I have this Docker file for a Lambda function written in Python:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/docker/library/python:3.10-slim-bullseye as build

WORKDIR /root

RUN apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install -y curl git git-lfs

RUN git clone --depth=1 https://huggingface.co/nlpconnect/vit-gpt2-image-captioning
RUN rm -rf vit-gpt2-image-captioning/.git

########################################

FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.10

WORKDIR ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

COPY --from=build /root/vit-gpt2-image-captioning ./vit-gpt2-image-captioning

COPY requirements.txt main.py ./

RUN pip3.10 install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["main.handler"]
```

With folder structure

```
folder/
  Dockerfile
  main.py
  requirements.txt
```

However I keep getting `[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'main'`.

I've checked the image files and it does contain the main.py so unsure why it's unable to import it.

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason could be that your main.py is not in the correct AWS Lambda Working Directory.

According to the AWS  documentation you need to copy your project's content to the `${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}`

Example Docker Image from [AWS S3 Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-image.html#python-image-instructions)

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.10

# Copy requirements.txt
COPY requirements.txt ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

# Copy function code
COPY lambda_function.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

# Install the specified packages
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Set the CMD to your handler (could also be done as a parameter override outside of the Dockerfile)
CMD [ "lambda_function.handler" ]
```